# 64 Bit download or Mac (AMD) download for HP Win 7 laptop AMD 8 quad core processor? Thanks!

Tags: dual-boot, hp, amd-processor

I am a bit confused.  I have a two year old HP dv7 Pavilion Laptop running 
Windows 7 home premium on a 720 GB hard drive with 77 GB free.

The laptop runs an AMD A8 quad core processor.  Which version of Ubuntu 14.04 
do I download and try to install?

atruefriend is my user name here and also at gmail.

I thank you in advance and hope to meet someone who lives near Sun City or Menifee, Calif 92586.  I can also drive into Temecula, Hemet, Perris or near by area and buy you coffee, 
as it has been many years since I looked at Linux and that was Red Hat 5 and 6.

Bobby Ray

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run the 64 bit versions of Ubuntu - both 12.04 and 14.04 are long-term-support (lts).  My pavilion dv7-4263 did not work well under 14.04, and I reverted to 12.04 for it - I had trouble with the graphics (radeon) in the 14.04 release, which *may* have been fixed by now.